# UnityEngine.UI.VerticalLayoutGroup не располагает объекты по сетке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Задача - расположить объекты по сетке. Для этого пробовал VerticalLayoutGroup, HorisontalLayoutGroup, GridLayoutGroup.

Проблема заключается в том, что при динамическом добавлении объектов, все эти объекты появляются в нулевых локальных координатах и не распределяются по сетке. Пробовал просто вручную накидывать объекты на сцене - всё работает (кто бы сомневался..)

Итак, код добавления объектов:

```
public GameObject grid;
void Start () {
        foreach (var item in Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("prefabs/bodies"))
        {
            GameObject temp = Instantiate(new GameObject(item.GetComponent<Body_variables>().bodyName), grid.transform, false);
            temp.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
            temp.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = temp.name;
            temp.GetComponent<TextMesh>().fontSize = fontSize;
            bodies.Add(temp);
        }
        foreach (var item in Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("prefabs/weapons"))
        {
            GameObject temp = Instantiate(new GameObject(item.GetComponent<Weapon_variables>().weaponName), grid.transform, false);
            temp.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
            temp.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = temp.name;
            temp.GetComponent<TextMesh>().fontSize = fontSize;
            weapons.Add(temp);
        }
    }
```

В GameObject grid передается объект, содержащий компонент VerticalLayoutGroup
Вот он:
[image: Скрин объекта]

Иерархия:

[image: Иерархия]

Сам скрипт Висит на MainCamera и в него передается объект Content.

Вот что получается в результате:

[image: Результат]

Все объекты висят в нулевых координатах. Нагугливание проблемы выдало множество способов решения, попробовал все, ничего не помогло. Вот они прямо по списку:

```
        grid.GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>().enabled = false;
        grid.GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>().enabled = true;
        Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
        grid.GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>().SetLayoutVertical();
        grid.GetComponent<ContentSizeFitter>().SetLayoutVertical();
        LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(grid.transform as RectTransform);
```

Параметры компонентов пробовал менять, собственно результата ноль.
Где я туплю? выручайте (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете компонент TextMesh - это 3d текст для сцены, а не интерфейса.
LayoutGroup с ним не работают. Используйте базовый [Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html).

Если вам нужно какое-то особое оформление текста, можете в ассет сторе скачать [TextMeshPro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/beta-projects/textmesh-pro-84126) - там у них своя реализация.

И ещё. Делать Canvas дочерним объектом камеры не обязательно - это ничего не даёт. Всё решает Render Mode установленный в компоненте.

И ешё2. Компонент VerticalLayoutGroup нужен для вертикальной сортировки компонентов, для построения сетки есть [GridLayoutGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html)